# How to write the exec command(in PHP) output to a file?

Tags: php

I will provide a example
i want the directory list to be written to a file
so i did this

```
<?php
$command="dir";
exec($command,$output);
//i want the directory list to be written to a file
// so i did this
$fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
fwrite($fp, $output);
//its actually writing the 0(return value for exec is int) to the file
// but i want the list of directories to be written to file
?>
```

its actually writing the 0(return value for exec is int) to the file
but i want the list of directories to be written to file
Please tell me a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [`shell_exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('dir');

    $fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
    fwrite($fp, $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that for your needle you should use the command "passthru".

Here an example:

```
<?php
    $command = exec('dir', $outpout);
    $data = "";
    foreach($output AS $key=>$val){
        $data .= $val . "\n";
    }

    $fp = fopen('file.txt', 'w') or die("i cant write...permission ?");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Let me know if it works

Have a nice day

Antonio

P.S. Thanks Kevin

Comment: Wrong. passthru directly display output and return void.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in the exec call (it's shorter) :

```
exec("dir > file.txt")
```

Anyway, your code is wrong because $output is an array.
Fixed code :

```
$command="dir";
exec($command,$output);
$fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
fwrite($fp, join("\n",$output))
```

And a shorter code :

```
exec("dir",$output);
file_get_contents("file.txt",join("\n",$output));
```

Comment: I think this is not exactly what he needs: though it's pretty compact, with this method you don't have control at all on the file you want to save to. Furthermore, if he wants to treat the output before saving it...